# How do you color the number in a numbered list using LaTeX

Tags: color

How do you color the number in a numbered list using LaTeX? 
Here is the beginning of my latex document.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      % dimensione carattere, no fronte/retro, tipo di documento
\usepackage{geometry}                       % per poter dare indicazioni su margini etc
\geometry{a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm}
% \usepackage{savetrees}            % togliere percentuale per far stare più cose in una pagina

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}                % pacchetti necessari per scrivere tutti i simboli matematici
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[default]{lato}              % tipo di carattere (noi di solito usiamo Lato)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % codifica dei font per scrivere in italiano (permette di vedere lettere accentate, p.e.)
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}           % codifica di input: LaTeX interpreta correttamente i caratteri che inserisco
\usepackage[italian]{babel}         % lingua del documento

\title{\color{SpringGreen} EQUAZIONI}
\date{}                         % togliendolo, visualizza la data del giorno (o data specifica che scriviamo tra graffe)

\begin{document}                    % inizia il documento
\maketitle                          % scrive il titolo che abbiamo scritto in \title{Titolo}
\thispagestyle{empty}               % pagina bianca, senza num. di pagina, testate o piè di pagina

\section{{\color{red} Risolvi le seguenti equazioni utilizzando le proprietà più adatte}}           % titolino per indicazioni esercizi\

%\subsection{}                      % se si volesse inserire un sottotitolo
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! Please create an account for this site (use the join this site button).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a full compilable code. In particular, I see no list?

Answer (score 4):

this is perhaps most easily done with the `enumitem` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textcolor{red}{\arabic*}\textcolor{green}{)}]
\item Zzzzzz
\item Wwwwww
\item Xxxxxx
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer! That colouring in the list numbering is pretty gopping though! :P

Comment: @Au101 I am a man of great taste and subtlety when it comes to typographic colour, see the `colortbl` manual for further examples.

Comment: Hm. Try \label + \ref.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer perhaps the colours are so pleasing you want them in the ref as well, otherwise I assume enumitem allows them to be separated, let me check....

Comment: You can use/should the format key. But if you really want two colors *and* the parenthese in the \ref one will have fiddle a bit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would add `ref=\arabic*` or `ref=\arabic*)` to get uncoloured references

Comment: Yes, that would work too.